# How to click on a checkbox after expanding the dropdown as per the HTML

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

```
**HTML:**

<div id="ctl05_ctl03_cblUser" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Silk" 
style="width:250px;white-space:normal;"> 
<table summary="combobox" border="0" style="border-width:0;border- 
collapse:collapse;width:100%" class="">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;">
<input name="ctl05$ctl03$cblUser" type="text" class="rcbInput 
 radPreventDecorate" id="ctl05_ctl03_cblUser_Input" value="" autocomplete="off">
</td>
<td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight">
<a id="ctl05_ctl03_cblUser_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: 
block;position: relative;outline: none;">select
</a>
</td> 
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input id="ctl05_ctl03_cblUser_ClientState" 
 name="ctl05_ctl03_cblUser_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
 </div>
 <div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index: 6000; display: block; width: 250px; 
  top: 362.594px; left: 247px; overflow: visible;">
<div id="ctl05_ctl03_cblUser_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown 
  RadComboBoxDropDown_Silk " style="width: 248px; display: block; top: 0px; 
    visibility: visible; transition: none;">
<div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="height: 345px;">
<ul class="rcbList">
<li class="rcbItem">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">John, Smith</label>: :after
 </li>
 <li class="rcbItem"><label>
 <input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Jane, Dow</label>: :after
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Added code from comment here for further analysis.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Silk'][contains(@id,'_cblUser_DropDown')]//ul[@class='rcbList']//label[contains(.,'John, Smith')]/input[@class='rcbCheckBox']")).click();

Comment: Which browser are you attempting to automate with Selenium? And what is the configuration? 

Do any other functions apart from clicking a checkbox work?

Comment: @CodeJockey - its chrome and it expands the dropdown but doesn't select/click the  the checkbox item. Dropdown expands & closes.

Comment: Perhaps try giving each checkbox element an Id. That way you only have to enter the Id and you won't have to muck around with these overly complicated selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the checkbox using the below xpath.I have specified sample to select the checkbox based on the name (Jane, Dev)

**Xpath:** `//div[@class='rcbSlide']//ul[@class='rcbList']//*[contains(text(),'Jane, Dev')]/input`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='rcbSlide']//ul[@class='rcbList']//*[contains(text(),'Jane, Dev')]/input")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I don't see anything wrong with your logic. You can wait for the element to be clickable before clicking it.

```
 WebElement ddl = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl05_ctl03_cblUser_Arrow"));
 ddl.click();
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
 WebElement lis = driver.findElement(By.className("rcbItem"));
 WebElement checkBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(lis.findElement(By.className("rcbCheckBox")))); 
 checkBox.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to `click()` on the *Check Box* with text as **John, Smith** you can use the following solutions:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft']/input[@class='rcbInput radPreventDecorate'][contains(@id,'User_Input')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Silk'][contains(@id,'_cblUser_DropDown')]//ul[@class='rcbList']//label[contains(.,'John, Smith')]/input[@class='rcbCheckBox']")).click();
```

Comment: @John Are you sure that the Dropdown is getting expanded?

Comment: @John Okay, are you sure that the top two lines of the HTML identifies the Dropdown element uniquely?

Comment: @John Can you please update the actual question with this information for further analysis?

Comment: @John Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status. Moving forward, when you update any question, append the additional information and please don't delete any existing context from the question or delete any comments. Else debugging becomes difficult.

Comment: @ DebanjanB -  Thanks for the updated answer but none of it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Before clicking on dropdown options make sure you are giving enough wait time to dropdown options to be visible. You can try couple of options.
For Jane, Dow

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li#rcbItem>label>input")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='rcbItem']/label/input")).click();

//if you know the text
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[text()='Jane, Dow']")).click();
```